# Nest Data Under Column in Associative Table

Tags: sql, json, database, postgresql

I am trying to produce a nested JSON file with a PostgreSQL database. I have three tables: Person_tbl, Log_tbl, Person_Log_tbl, where the latter is an associative table containing Person_id and Log_id as foreign keys to the previous tables. I want the end result to look something like this:

```
{
    username: 
      log1 {
        log_id: 1,
        activity_id: 1,
        logdate: 2016-10-25
      }
      log2 {
        log_id: 2,
        activity_id: 1,
        logdate: 2016-10-26
      }
    username2: 
     ....
}
```

Right now I have a SQL query that returns 1 log under each user, with the same user being returned for however many logs they have. I can't figure out how to join all logs together under the correct user. Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT p.username, row_to_json(l.*)
 FROM person_log_tbl pl
  INNER JOIN person_tbl p on pl.person_id = p.person_id
  INNER JOIN log_tbl l on pl.log_id = l.log_id
  GROUP BY p.username, l.log_id
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to aggregate the values together and remove `l.log_id` from the `group by`:

```
SELECT p.username, json_agg(l.*)
FROM person_log_tbl pl INNER JOIN
     person_tbl p
     ON pl.person_id = p.person_id INNER JOIN
     log_tbl l 
     ON pl.log_id = l.log_id
GROUP BY p.username;
```